# From version X up

Tags: phrase-request

Is it correct (and formal enough for a resume) to say "I'm familiar with this software package from version 2.0 up", meaning that I'm familiar with version 2.0 and all subsequent versions of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a native of the UK, I would say that your suggestion "I'm familiar with this software package from version X up" is close.

First of all, it makes more sense to use "and upwards":

> I am familiar with version X and upwards.

Other ways to phrase this sentence are:

- I have used the package since version X.
- I am familiar with version X and later.

Comment: I like the "**I'm familiar with version X and later.**" and met it a lot of times myself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think I'll go with the "and upwards" thing.

Answer (score -1):

With the original sentence we could rephrase it to:

- *I'm familiar with this software package from version 2.0 (and) higher*
- *I'm familiar with this software package from version 2.0 (and) later*

There are other ways to say it:

- "*I'm familiar with this software package **since version 2.0***"
- "*I'm familiar with this software package **starting with version 2.0***"

All of these imply version 2.0 and all the versions that came later.

Comment: I don't agree with this. To me, "I'm familiar since version X" doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't agree with this, either. I find nothing odd or unidiomatic about "from version 2.0 up".

Comment: @J.R. I respect your knowledge but would want to know whether omitting **and** before **up** makes it correct?

Comment: @SovereignSun - The word _and_ can indeed be elided in such contexts. (It's not unlike constructs such as _from 1980 onwards_.)